# Does AWS security group block unintentionally exposed ports from Docker?

Tags: account-security, ports, aws, docker

My typical cloud server hardening includes blocking ports at the UFW level on the server as well as at the AWS security group level.

I recently learned that Docker [overwrites your IPTables](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/). Given that, I had previously blocked a port `x` with UFW, but also published port `x` with Docker, which I believe negates my UFW status.

Did my AWS security group settings still block this port `x` from being exposed to the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS security groups are independent from your server settings. If you had IPTables open to everything but a AWS security group blocking port 80, port 80 will be blocked.

Therefor, the AWS security groups will still block port `x` if configured to do so even if the IPTable rules allow the same port.

I recommend you read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/286665/why-have-both-security-groups-and-iptables-on-amazon-ec2) about the differences.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Security Group is a Allowed List based host firewall (attached to ENI).
Therefore, if you have not added a firewall rule to *allow* traffic to this specific port (+ from specific IP range) in your AWS Security Group(s) attached to the relevant resource, AWS SG will block that port.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

> "Characteristics of security group rules
>
> - You can specify allow rules, but not deny rules.
>
> ...
>
> - When you associate multiple security groups with a resource, the rules from each security group are aggregated to form a single set of
>   rules that are used to determine whether to allow access."